# Mysql many to many selecting data - possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, many-to-many

I have 2 tables that gets joined in a 3 table, so that there is a many to many relationship, and I am trying to get all users and show them once, but with all the users user groups

```
Users
- user_id
- email

groups
- group_id
- broup_name

users_groups
- users_groups_id
- user_id
- group_id
```

I am trying to get all the users and display each user once, but with all the users user groups, like shown here:

```
some@user.dk - admin, moderator, public
another@user.dk - moderator, public
```

Is it even possible to select the data like this or do you have to sort it in the code instead?

Comment: It's called a ["JOIN"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). In this particular case there are two joins across the [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Comment: @user2864740 This is more. It's about concatenating the joined results into a single string.

Comment: @Carsten That's a slightly different question (or rather a secondary question), of which there are many duplicates. The JOIN - and concepts behind which - comes first. The OP hasn't even shown an initial M-M "selection".

Comment: @user2864740 Sure the JOIN comes first. But I'm not sure if this question is about the join itself or about the concatenation. Or maybe about the combination...

Comment: @Carsten Without the join there is no reason to discuss grouping and denormalization/aggregation of the results.

Comment: I have tried various joins and should have specified that in the question. The post by Ollie Jones below answered my question so it was the right track that @carsten was on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It's even easy.

```
SELECT email, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT group_name ORDER BY g.group_id) AS groups
  FROM Users AS u
  JOIN users_groups AS ug ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
  JOIN Groups AS g on ug.group_id = g.group_id
 GROUP BY email
 ORDER BY email
```

That will display one line per email, with the distinct groups belonging to that user shown in order of group id.  T